# I can't make a 1-character grammatical correction

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I tried to change "your's" (which is not a word) to "yours" (which is).  That was the only thing wrong with the answer, but, since edits must be at least 6 characters, the system would not let me make the correction.

Comment: Is that *really* an effective edit? I mean, is it going to change if the post is understood or not?

Comment: Link to the post?

Comment: Correct grammar is always a good thing.  The post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967454/instantiation-of-viewmodels-and-service-classes/16980207#16980207

Answer (score 13):

Earn enough reputation to get editing privileges (you need 2000 rep), and you can make single-character edits without approval, if you wish.

That said, single-character edits are extremely rare.  Usually, there are other problems with the post that also need correction.  Be respectful of reviewers' time and fix the whole post, not just a single character.

Comment: are those with 2k reputation can do minor edits as much as they want?

Comment: As long as they are appropriate edits, yes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Thanks for the info, but take a look at the post and tell me if it needs fixing.  I think not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967454/instantiation-of-viewmodels-and-service-classes/16980207#16980207

Comment: [There you go](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16980207/revisions), @DirkMass! A very comprehensive answer, but a good bit of change to be made!

Comment: When editing some programming language's code, one character can be _very_ important. Perhaps the rule could be different when it is in a code  block?

Comment: I just had this issue in the review queue, trying to fix a list rendering that would've only required a newline. Wasn't allowed to.